# Radio button not posting value to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I have a form that is being updated by PHP to a MySQL database.  I have two radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="show_on_website" value="Y" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="show_on_website" value="N" /> No
```

Upon clicking on the **Yes** or **No** radio button and submitting the form, the value Y or N, depending on which is selected does not get submitted into the MySQL database.  All other data within the form is updating fine, just not the radio buttons.  I am using `$show_on_website = $POST['show_on_website'];` upon submitting the form.

What am I missing or doing wrong?  Thanks for any help you may provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$_POST` instead of `$POST`

Comment: Seriously, do you know how much time I have spent on this and how many times I have checked and re-checked my code and I missed something so simple.  Thanks much!!

Comment: sometimes, you just need a fresh set of eyes