# How to set the Radio Button based on the value fetched from the database

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jradiobutton

I have a `JTable` filled with data about `students (student id, name...)`, and when I select a row from a table, the form opens and its field need to be filled with same values (eg. if Johny Bravo was selected from the table.

Then his name should be shown in text filed Name on the form, I did like this `txtfieldName.setText(student.getName)`.

My question is how do I set my `Radio button` automatically (my radio button is Male or Female) when I clicked the field.

```
enter code here

tableGuest.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    try{
        int row = tableGuest.getSelectedRow();
        String guestEdit=(tableGuest.getModel().getValueAt(row,     0).toString());


        String query = "Select guest_id,guest_fname,guest_lname,guest_contact,guest_age,guest_gender,guest_address,guest_email from guest_tbl where guest_id= '"+guestEdit+"'";

    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    buttonGroupEdit.add(rdbtnMaleEdit);
    buttonGroupEdit.add(rdbtnFemaleEdit);


                while(rs.next())
                {
                    String genderEdit=rs.getString("guest_gender"); 

                    if(genderEdit.equals("Male"))
                    {
                         rdbtnMaleEdit.setSelected(true); 
                    }
                    else if(genderEdit.equals("Female"))
                    {
                         rdbtnFemaleEdit.setSelected(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error !");
                    }


                    tfEditFname.setText(rs.getString("guest_fname"));
                    tfEditLname.setText(rs.getString("guest_lname"));
                    tfEditEmail.setText(rs.getString("guest_email"));

                    tfEditContact.setText(rs.getString("guest_contact"))
                }
                pst.close();


            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You need to evaluate the value of `sex` to a `boolean` (`true`/`false`) which can the be set to the `JRadioButton` via `isSelected`.  You might also like to have a look at [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html)

Comment: Some idea of the structure of the `Student` class would be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio button not posting value to MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770199/radio-button-not-posting-value-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Thank you guys! but I'm stuck in that radiobutton I can't set it based on database

Answer (score 0):

```
    String gender = "male" 
    // this comes from db - since we don't know the structure this is a plain guess.

    if (gender.equals("male") {
        rbtMale.setSelected(true); 
    } else {
        rbtFemale.setSelected(true); 
    }
```

And like MadProgrammer said, you will need a `ButtonGroup` and `add` all relevant buttons to it.

```
private final ButtonGroup genderButtons = new ButtonGroup();
genderButtons.add(rbtMale);
genderButtons.add(rbtFemale);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help! But I need to set my radio button automatically based from the database

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with same kinda solution in my work I am generating radiobutton with database values and showing them in java dialog.

We have a values from database stored in list like below:

> List Titles; //This is a list containing your database values

First count the values of this list elements:

> int list_count=Titles.size();

Now to proceed with radio function first we need to convert list elements into array like below:

```
String[] col = new String[list_count]; //created an array with limit of list count values
for(int i=0; i < list_count; i++){ 
col[i]=Titles.get(i).toString(); // add values of list into array with loop
}
```

Below is the function that is creating radio buttons with database array we created above:

```
 public String get_key(int list_count, String[] col){

   JRadioButton jb[] = new JRadioButton[col.length]; //Create Radion button array

   ButtonGroup rb = new ButtonGroup(); //Group Radio Button

   JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) ); //Set layout of radion button to display each after other

   JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(panel); // Create a scrollpane to put all these radio button on that

   GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout(); //Layout for scrollpane

sp.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED)); //bordre for scrollpane

    List<Component> q = new ArrayList<>(); // q is a component to store and display each radio button

    JLabel h1=new JLabel("Select a value"); //put a heading on top of jpanel before radio button

    h1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18)); // set heading text

    panel.add(h1); //add heading on top of jpanel

    panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)); //set panel border to padding each radio button

    for(int i=0; i < list_count; i++){ 

     jb[i]=new JRadioButton(col[i]); //create radion button dynamacially "col[i]" is the value of each radio

     rb.add(jb[i]); //it is important also to put all radio in a group we created so only one element should be selected

     panel.add(jb[i]); // add all radio on jpanel

        }

sp.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 350, 300 ) ); //set size of scrollpane

int act=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, sp, "Select Primary Key",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //add and show scrollpane in dialog

}
```

Calling this function with parameter values we created first "list_count" & "col":

```
get_key(list_count, col);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Student.java` class to get particular table value from database.
In the current form `AddStudent` create a function call as `getStudentList` to fill the GUI form with database data to particular id.

```
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentList() {
    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    conn = DbConnection.ConnectDb();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM student";

    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement();
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        Donor donor;

        while(rs.next()) {
            student = new Student(rs.getString("id"),
            rs.getString("gender"));
            studentList.add(student);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return studentList; 
}
```

After create a function called `showStudent` to show the particular data value to called id.(In below code `male,female` are the checkbox values)

```
    public void showStudent(int index) throws ParseException {
    if(getStudentList().get(index).getGender().equals("male")) {
                male.setSelected(true);
                female.setSelected(false);
                gender = "male";
            }
            else {
                female.setSelected(true);
                male.setSelected(false);
                gender = "female";
            }
    }
```

Set action to the `jbutton`, When get value id from `jtextfield` then fill the checkbox in particular gender value.